# Swift ScrollView - contentSize can't take a variable Int

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, cgfloat, cgsize

Trying to set a scrollView's contentSize and I've run across this issue (Xcode 6.4)...

Both of these work perfectly:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.frame.width, height:1000)

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, 1000)
```

Once a let (or var) gets involved, these do not work:

```
let testing = 1000
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.frame.width, height:testing)
```

Error: Cannot find an initializer for type 'CGSize' that accepts an argument list of type '(width: CGFloat, height: Int)'

```
let testing = 1000
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, testing)
```

Error: Cannot invoke 'CGSizeMake' with an argument list of type '(CGFloat, Int)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `let` statement to the following:

```
let testing:CGFloat = 1000
```

You need to do this as the `CGSizeMake` function requires two parameters of the same type, so you can either make both `int`s or make them both `CGFloat`s. In this case it is probably easier to use `testing` as a `CGFloat` in the first place. In other cases, you might want to try something like

```
let testing = 1000
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(Int(self.view.frame.width), testing)
```

Or:

```
let testing = 1000
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, CGFloat(testing))
```

So that both are of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

- A number literal doesn't have an explicit type. Its type is inferred at the point that it's evaluated by the compiler.
- A number variable must have an explicit type. The default type is `Int`

  ```
  let testing : CGFloat = 1000.0
  scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.frame.width, height:testing)
  ```